# Position all slides titles at the same exact coordinate - Keynote

Tags: macos, catalina, keynote

So I have about 70 slides in my keynote presentation.

[image]

I've been looking everywhere trying to position **all** my titles of all `70` pages to start at the exact x,y coordinates position.

I couldn't find it an option to do that.

Result :

Right now, if I pressed down arrows, I see that my titles are not line up, some of them are too far left, and some are slightly off not in same position because I been eyes-ball and position each one of them best I can to the left edge.

Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/32222/313842 https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/keynote-ipad/tan7a2b69972/ipados

Comment: Is there an issue wit editing the master layout so each slide has the same title placement? Change things and then reapply the master should work unless I’m. Issuing your point entirely. https://support.apple.com/guide/keynote/apply-a-master-slide-tan584189747/mac

Comment: I don’t now master work. I tried it I see 2 yellow lines. I’m not sure how is it going to help me do what I need.

Comment: The image showing _slide_ 20, actually does not have a _title_ as the **[] Title** check box is unchecked. The _object_ containing "Click Jacking" is a `text item` not a `default title item`. If all the _slides_ follow the same pattern, then set the _first_ `text item` on the _first_ `slide` to the `position` you want and then to get the same _object_ on each _slide_ to the same `position` you can use a bit of **AppleScript** _code_ run in **Script Editor**, e.g.: `tell application "Keynote" to tell document 1 to set position of text item 1 of slides to (position of text item 1 of slide 1)`

Comment: @user3439894, the screenshot only show 20, but I have over 100 slides now. I only about 70 the day I posted this question.

Comment: @user3439894 : Feel free to add your comment as answer, I'm sure others will be able to benefit from it.

Comment: kyo, did the suggestion I made in my first comment work for you?

Answer (score 1):

From Keynote type some text on a slide. Select the text and on the top right side be sure to click on Format. Then on the line below Format click on Arrange. In the pane that appears, you can set the x and y positions of the text. There is an option below that to lock this into place.

Comment: Yes. I saw that but that is to arrange only one slide. I have 70 of them. I’m trying to avoid doing each of them.

Comment: You answer refer to only one slide, I am not looking for that. I am looking for a solution for all my titles.